# Selecting max value while group by two columns with order on another column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have table with 4 rows
`id   season_id  market  elements` I would like to select for each same season_id, market that hold  max result and if max results are the same then max based on elements only where elements are higher than 9.

```
id  | season_id | market | result    | elements
 1  |    20     |   fh   |    75     |   20
 2  |    20     |   fh   |    75     |   22
 3  |    20     |   SH   |    81     |   18
 4  |    20     |   SH   |    75     |   20
 5  |    21     |   fh   |    90     |   14
 6  |    21     |   fh   |    86     |   16
 7  |    21     |   SH   |    90     |   18
 8  |    21     |   SH   |    91     |   2
```

I would like to get

```
   id  | season_id | market | result    | elements
    2  |    20     |   fh   |    75     |   22
    3  |    20     |   SH   |    81     |   18
    5  |    21     |   fh   |    90     |   14
    7  |    21     |   SH   |    90     |   18
```

I've tried

```
  SELECT a.* FROM results a INNER JOIN (SELECT id, market, MAX(result) as perc FROM 
  results where elements>9 group by market ) group ON a.market = group.market and 
  a.result = group.perc group by market
```

But it doesn't select all the markets and I'm not sure how to add selection by number of elements to that

Comment: I don't understand the restriction on elements > 9.  What if there are none?

Comment: then skip this record

Comment: are there multiple records (meaning 3 and above here) with the same season_id and market or is it always either 1 or 2?

Comment: there are multiple records on market and season_id, but each season id has the same number and name of the markets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want one result per `season_id`/`market` pair.  I'm not 100% sure what the limit on `elements > 9` is supposed to be doing, but I think it is an overall filter.

To get the rows with the maximum result and elements for each season and market, use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by season_id, market order by result desc, elements desc) as seqnum
      from t
      where elements > 9
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0064b758223f2bfe3c167557bef0751a) is a db<>fiddle.

In older versions of MySQL (or even more recent versions), you can use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.id = (select t2.id
              from t t2
              where t2.season_id = t.season_id and t2.market = t.market and
                    t2.elements > 9
              order by t2.result desc, t2.elements desc
              limit 1
             );
```

Comment: Thank you I can see this solution is working, but I didn't mention that the table has 150k rows and this query takes too long to complete the request

Comment: @user2741313 . . . The first query should be fine.  In any case, an index on `(season_id, market, result desc, elements desc, id)` should help either query.

Comment: So the first query doesn't work I get error, after creating the index on all the columns the second query worked but it took over 50 sec. Do you think there is a way to improve the performance of that

Comment: Why doesn't the first query work?  I have a db<>fiddle showing that both work.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(partition by season_id, market order by result desc, elements desc) as ' at line 3

Comment: @user2741313 . . . You are using an older version of MySQL.  If you upgrade to a version released since April 2018, you'll have the window functions (and more!).

Comment: Unfortunately in not possible on my share server